# Removing value from a List in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a 'Deal or No Deal' type game for a project in Visual Basic 2008.

I'm having a problem assigning the 5 values randomly to 5 boxes.

For example, in one game, the boxes could hold these values:

```
Box 1 = 1000 
Box 2 = 35000
Box 3 = 25000
Box 4 = 75000
Box 5 = 5000
```

and in another game, they could hold these values

```
Box 1 = 75000 
Box 2 = 25000
Box 3 = 1000
Box 4 = 5000
Box 5 = 35000
```

The main aim is to randomly assign these values to each box, and once a value has been assigned, it cannot be assigned to another box at the same time.

Here is the code that I have at the moment:

```
        Dim values As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim box(4) As Integer
        Dim randNum(4) As Integer

        'adding values to the Value list
        values.Add(1000)
        values.Add(5000)
        values.Add(25000)
        values.Add(35000)
        values.Add(75000)

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 4
            Dim RandomClass As New Random()
            Dim RandomNumber As Integer
            RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 4)

            'assigning a box a random value form the list
            box(i) = values(RandomNumber)

            'removing that value from the list
            values.RemoveAt(i)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Box 1 = " & box(0))
        Console.WriteLine("Box 2 = " & box(1))
        Console.WriteLine("Box 3 = " & box(2))
        Console.WriteLine("Box 4 = " & box(3))
        Console.WriteLine("Box 5 = " & box(4))

        Console.Read()
```

VB keeps returning this error message when I try t run the application:

*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index*

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: if you remove a value from the list, the list gets shorter and the result of the next randomvalue may well refer to one of the things you got rid of. set a breakpoint and debug it to see.  one thing you may want to look into is a Shuffle

Comment: ah that makes sense, would you be able to give me more information on this?

Comment: if you want there to be no chance of repeating a value (as with a deck of cards where there is only one Ace of Spades), then you want to create a list of possible values, shuffle them and then just assign them.  Investigate the Fisher-Yates shuffle - oodles of examples of it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an item, the length of the list gets smaller. So on the second loop, index of 4 no longer exists. On the third loop, 3 no longer exists and so on. Try this instead:

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
For i = 0 To 4
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, values.count - 1)

    'assigning a box a random value form the list
    box(i) = values(RandomNumber)

    'removing that value from the list
    values.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Steve prevents the error from occurring, but I think it's still not doing quite what you want. `values.RemoveAt(i)` will always remove the first item from the list the first time, the second, next time, etc... it is not removing the value that you have just put in the box. To do that you should use `values.RemoveAt(RandomNumber)` instead.

```
For i = 0 To 4
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, values.count - 1)

    'assigning a box a random value form the list
    box(i) = values(RandomNumber)

    'removing that value from the list
    values.RemoveAt(RandomNumber)
Next
```

Comment: yes, i have already implemented that myself, thank you for the answer though

Comment: Good catch, I was looking at the error and missed other issues in the code.